# check for valid date which is declared in varchar2

Tags: sql, oracle

My table looks like below which is declared in VARCHAR2:

```
YMD  
20101010  
20101112  
20100231  
20150101  
20160101
```

I have to check for valid dates and filter future dates from sysdate, which are in valid format.

I write the function as below to check for valid dates:

```
create or replace FUNCTION VALIDATE_DATE (p_string in string) return date is  
begin  
    return to_date(p_string, 'YYYYMMDD');  
exception when others then  
    begin  
        return to_date(p_string, 'YYYY-MM-DD');  
    exception when others then  
        begin  
            return to_date(p_string, 'RR-MON-DD');  
        exception when others then  
            return null;  
        end;  
    end;  
end;
```

and written this query to check for valid dates and replace with null for invalid dates

```
select ymd, VALIDATE_DATE(ymd) as Valid 
from temp
```

and to check future dates I wrote the following query, but it throws error

> ORA-01839

```
select ymd 
from temp
where validate_date(ymd)='YES'
and to_date(ymd,'yyyymmdd')>sysdate
```

How to check future dates in my table if exists?

Comment: Your `validate_date` function returns a `date`, but you check the result against `'YES'`. You might want to check that.

Comment: Use validate_date(ymd)>sysdate

Comment: At first, DO NOT store DATE as VARCHAR2. All this overhead is due to the fact that your design is flawed. Add another column with data type DATE. And then do the required date arithmetic on the new date column, drop the old column, rename the new column to old column.

Comment: I agree with Lalit. Never, ever store dates as varchar. Just don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will rather fix the **design issue** as a permanent fix rather than wasting time on the workaround.

Firstly, **NEVER** store **DATE** as **VARCHAR2**. All this overhead is due to the fact that your **design is flawed**.

> '20100231'

***How on earth could that be a valid date? Which calendar has a 31 days in FEBRUARY?***

Follow these steps:

1. Add a new column with DATE DATA TYPE.
2. Update the new column with date values from the old column using **TO_DATE**.
3. Do the required DATE arithmetic on the new DATE column, or handle this in the UPDATE statement in step 2 itself.
4. Drop the old column.
5. Rename the new column to the old column.

**UPDATE** Adding a demo

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t
  2      (ymd varchar2(8));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2      INTO t (ymd)
  3           VALUES ('20101112')
  4      --INTO t (ymd)
  5      --     VALUES ('20100231')
  6      INTO t (ymd)
  7           VALUES ('20150101')
  8      INTO t (ymd)
  9           VALUES ('20160101')
 10  SELECT * FROM dual;

3 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

**Add new column:**

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE t ADD (dt DATE);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

**DO the required update**

```
SQL> UPDATE t
  2  SET dt =
  3    CASE
  4      WHEN to_date(ymd, 'YYYYMMDD') > SYSDATE
  5      THEN NULL
  6      ELSE to_date(ymd, 'YYYYMMDD')
  7    END;

3 rows updated.

SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

**Let's check:**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

YMD      DT
-------- ---------
20101112 12-NOV-10
20150101 01-JAN-15
20160101

SQL>
```

**Drop the old column:**

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE t DROP COLUMN ymd;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

**Rename the new column to old column name**

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE t RENAME COLUMN dt TO ymd;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

**You have just fixed the issue**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

YMD
---------
12-NOV-10
01-JAN-15


SQL>
```

Comment: that is my input data so I have to check for valid dates and correct them later

Comment: I work in OEDQ,that is my input data given in varchar2 so I have to check for valid dates and correct them later and 20100231 is also in my input data by using the function i can check for invalid dates and correct them but in millions of data i have to check any future dates are mentioned so i can check once and publish them but unable to check

Comment: A date doesn't have a format. The format you see is displayed in a way human beings could interpret. You should take the input as a DATE and not VARCHAR2.

Comment: Thank you for the solution i can add a column and check