# TO_DATE Not a valid month error in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my query

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT TO_DATE(INV_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') INVOICE_DATE
          FROM SAPSCH.SAP_TABLE T
         WHERE T.INV_DATE <> '00000000')
 WHERE INVOICE_DATE = '14-Sep-2012';
```

`SAPSCH.SAP_TABLE` is a view which uses a dblink to connect to a SAP schema. The column `INV_DATE` is in the format 'YYYYMMDD'. For example, '20120914' for '14-Sep-2012'. The inner query is returning 15k+ records. But when I run the full query it's giving me this error:

> **ORA-01843: not a valid month**

Comment: Why are you doing two date conversions and a subselect when you could do the query directly?

Comment: I suspect there are few values which are malformed and not a valid date.
I just answered a similar question, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625519/check-for-valid-date-which-is-declared-in-varchar2

DO NOT store DATE as VARCHAR2. All this overhead is due to the fact that your design is flawed. Add another column with data type DATE. And then do the required date arithmetic on the new date column, drop the old column, rename the new column to old column.

Comment: @Lalit: while that's generally good advice, SAP is a large ERP product, changing the schema is possible but comes at a relatively large cost in terms of maintenance. (And the change you suggest is simply not supported/possible in most cases.)

Comment: I think the workaround here would be, to first catch all the bad values in an exception block, and then remove those malformed dates. For example, `'20100231'` is not a valid date. And will throw `ORA-01843: not a valid month`

Answer (score 0):

There are two places in your query that could cause the error:

1. `WHERE INVOICE_DATE = '14-Sep-2012'` only works in database settings where 'Sep' is a valid abbreviation for a month (in English for example). Otherwise you'd get the error described.
2. Your SAP database may contain incorrect data such as '20151301' which would also trigger this error.

In your simple query you could of course simply write the following ;-)

```
SELECT DATE'2012-09-14' AS INVOICE_DATE
FROM SAPSCH.SAP_TABLE T
WHERE T.INV_DATE = '20120914';
```

If, however, you want to deal with all dates, not only with September 14, 2012, then you would have to check for the dates to be valid. Unfortunately Oracle has no such check function that I know of. So you cannot solve this with SQL alone, but need PL/SQL:

```
-- Return the date from the SAP string or NULL for invalid date strings
create or replace function f_get_date_from_sap_datestring(vi_sap_datestring varchar2)
  return date as
begin
  return to_date(vi_sap_datestring, 'yyyymmdd');
exception when others then
  return null;
end;
```

And then:

```
select f_get_date_from_sap_datestring(inv_date) as invoice_date
from sapsch.sap_table
where f_get_date_from_sap_datestring(inv_date) is not null;
```

Comment: 1) My database will accept '14-Sep-2012'.  
2) The inner query is returning all rows without any errors if I run it separately which means there is no incorrect data.

Comment: Okay, then Oracle has difficulties to convert '14-Sep-2012' into a date, I guess. At last it is just a string and you don't tell the dbms how to convert it. Never use just some date string instead of a date. Either use date literals ( e.g. `DATE'2012-09-14'`) or a date conversion (e.g. `to_date('14-sep-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')`). As you see, when converting month names, always specify NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE in order to have it run independent from the settings.

Answer (score 0):

It is always adviceable to use the explicit conversion using to_date to 14-Sep-2012

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT TO_DATE(INV_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') INVOICE_DATE
      FROM SAPSCH.SAP_TABLE T
     WHERE T.INV_DATE ='20120914')
WHERE INVOICE_DATE = to_date('14-Sep-2012','DD-Mon-YYYY');
```