# sql oracle update date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

My table `table1` has the column `date_txt` which includes `2/16/2011 12:00:00 AM` - column `date_txt` is `VARCHAR2 (250 Char)`.

My table `table1` also has the column `date` which is a `DATE`.

I would like to "update" my field:

The final output should be:

table1:

```
 date

 2/16/2011
```

So it takes from `table1` `date_txt` the "date" and updates it to the column `date` as a date.

Any ideas? I am a bloody beginner.

Comment: Take a look on the TO_DATE function http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Comment: Why store date/time in varchar columns? Why store same data twice?

Comment: @jarlh I imported the date from a excel file which is a varchar now but I want it in another column as a date

Comment: I see, and then you'll remove the date_txt column?

Comment: Its okay if its empty - so no we dont remove it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Oracle's [to_date function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) to convert a string to a date:

```
update table1 set "date" = to_date(date_txt, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:ss AM')
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ccd0/1)

Comment: Thanks  - I had to add a bit to fix my problem:

'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:ss AM'

Answer (score 1):

> column date_txt which includes 2/16/2011 12:00:00 AM

- Firstly, **DATE** doesn't have any **format**. What you see is for **display** purpose to interpret date value easily.
- Secondly, you should **never ever store DATE as VARCHAR2**. This is a big problem and a poor design.

Now that you have a bad design, it is a good idea to fix it right now.

**Follow these steps:**

1. Add a new column with **DATE data type**.
2. Update the new column with date values from the old column using **TO_DATE**.
3. **Drop** the old column.
4. **Rename** the new column to the old column.

I have already answered how to do it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29625772/3989608

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
update table1 set date=
    (select to_date(date_txt,'dd/mm/yyyy') from table1 where id=yourId) where id=yourId;
```

Use primary key columns for ids.

If this is what you need everytime. I would suggest you to use [Triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm)

Comment: No subquery required here?

Comment: Yeah, and you don't need a subquery for that :)  See my answer for an example